# Custom Overlay in Google Maps API V3 Distortion

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am fairly new to using the Google Maps API, but I have been playing around with getting an overlay of a gridded PNG image into Google Maps. Here is the url: http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/~lkarsten/Alaska_SWE.html.

Just a little background on the image being displayed. It's a gridded PNG file displaying snow water equivalent values at 0.01 degree lat/lon resolution with the bounds of the image being 48.0 - 72.0 degrees latitude and -126.0 to -168.0 degrees longitude.

When I use the ground overlay function (google.maps.GroundOverlay), the image is overlayed correctly. This url has the correct overlay positioning using google.maps.GroundOverlay: http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/~lkarsten/Alaska_SWE.html.20120312.

However, I wish to add features to the overlay, such as opacity, etc. You cannot do that with the GroundOverlay function, so I have been using the google.maps.OverlayView function, but I am getting some sort of weird distortion to the image. The extents seem to be fine, but it's as if the image has been stretched in the middle. The image was generated in lat/lon coordinates, so I am not quite sure why the image is being distorted in this manner. Perhaps it has to do with the Google Maps API Mercator projection?

Has anyone else encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

GroundOverlay support opacity, according to the API reference. 
GroundOverlay class slides an image into multiple divs to minimize distortion for large areas. You need to implement similar logic if you want do a custom class.